# Is there a generalization of the divergence theorem for integrals of the form $\iint_S \vec F \, dS$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

I know the divergence theorem can be applied to closed flux integrals $$\iint_S \vec F \cdot d\vec S = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot \vec F \, dV$$ but what if I have an integral of the form $$\iint_S  F  \, d\vec S$$

where $S$ is some closed surface?  can Stokes's Theorem be neatly applied for it?

i.e. something like for a closed surface S enclosing a volume V where $d\vec S$ is an outward-oriented normal

$$\iint_S F\, d\vec S  \stackrel{?}{=} \iiint_V \nabla F \, dS$$?

Comment: $F\vec{dS}$ has three components, each of which can be written as something like $(F,0,0)\cdot \vec{dS}$, etc. Why not try taking this approach and proving/disproving your guess with a formula you can derive?

Comment: @NinadMunshi i did not think of that... thank you!  I tried it, and seemed to have gotten to that answer.  Am I correct?